# GROUP BY with ORDER BY <- ORDER BY TIMESTAMP is ignored

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Searched through the articles but couldn't find anything specific for solving my problem.

```
SELECT `id_von`, `message`, `timestamp` 
FROM  `messages` 
WHERE  `id_von` =  $session_user_id OR `id_re` = $session_user_id 
GROUP BY id_von 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Problem is it is not the newest entry. Its actually the first one in the DB.
Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: How is it that you have columns in your output which aren't aggregated or part of the `GROUP`?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is a data type in MySQL.  Can you try this again using `timestamp` *with the quotes* in your ORDER BY line?

Comment: please elaborate your question in detail what you want

Comment: [The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think this is the problem :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `group by`?

Answer (score 0):

It's more comment then answer, but I can't insert formatted code in comment. Possible problem with TIMESTAMP because it data type. Try to use alias:

```
SELECT m.id_von, m.message, m.timestamp 
FROM  messages m 
WHERE  m.id_von =  $session_user_id OR m.id_re = $session_user_id 
GROUP BY m.id_von 
ORDER BY m.TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Furthermore try to replace `ORDER BY m.TIMESTAMP DESC` upon `ORDER BY 3 DESC`

**UPD.** Using `group by` meaningful with aggregate function such as `sum`

Comment: you can put backticks in comments to codify.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Yeah but it's not as readable without linebreaks and indention